# Fmod + Unity + GVR : GVR Listener settings in Fmod

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, fmod, google-vr-sdk

We’re working on a `VR` project using `Fmod`, `Unity` and the `GVR` plugins. Here is our problem : in `Fmod`, when setting the `GVR` Listener on a bus that is *NOT* the **Master** bus, we get an error in Unity: `« Google GVR Listener not found in Fmod project »`.

In `Fmod`, is there a specific way to insert `GVR` Listener on a bus that is not the **Master**?
Also, we went a bit through `FmodGVRAudio.cs` and it seems that it’s returning `Null` when looking for `ChannelGroup` in any bus but the Master.
We use `Unity 5.6.1f1`, `Fmod Studio 1.09.04` and the *latest version* of `GVR` plugins for Unity.

Thanks!